# How to access members of thrust::device_vector<struct>

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, thrust

CUDA has some documentation found here: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html#vectors which allows the use of vector in device memory/code. I am trying to create a vector of a struct type to use for general processing. Here is the sample code:

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Data
{
  double first, second, total;
};

__global__
void add(thrust::device_vector<Data> *d_matrix)
{
  &d_matrix[1].total = &d_matrix[1].first + &d_matrix[1].second;
}

int main()
{
  thrust::host_vector<Data> matrix;
  thrust::device_vector<Data> *d_matrix;
  int size = sizeof(thrust::host_vector<Data>);

  matrix[1].first = 2100;
  matrix[1].second = 100;

  cudaMalloc(&d_matrix, size);

  cudaMemcpy(d_matrix, &matrix, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  add<<<1,1>>>(d_matrix);

  cudaMemcpy(&matrix, d_matrix, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cudaFree(d_matrix);

  std::cout << "The sum is: " << matrix[1].total;

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> gpuAnalysis.cu(13): error: class "thrust::device_vector>" has no member "total"
>
> gpuAnalysis.cu(13): error: class "thrust::device_vector>" has no member "first"
>
> gpuAnalysis.cu(13): error: class "thrust::device_vector>" has no member "second"
>
> 3 errors detected in the compilation of
>   "/tmp/tmpxft_000013c9_00000000-8_gpuAnalysis.cpp1.ii".

According to the documentation provided on the nvidia site, these vectors are able to store all data types as std::vector. Is there a way to fix this error to access the members of the struct with each vector element?

Comment: There is a lot wrong here. Even after you fix the allocation and operator precedence issues in the code, it won't work because you can't use thrust device vectors in device code,

Comment: Is there any way for me to use a vector in device code? I assumed that the documentation from Nvidia was saying that thrust device vectors allowed the use of vectors in device code.

Comment: Nowhere does the documentation state or imply that. You can access the memory backing a device vector in device code, but you cannot use the class itself.

Comment: Ok. I'm new to CUDA and not the most experienced programmer. Would you mind providing an answer with an examples of that?

Comment: Thank you my friend. The duplicate is what I was looking for. I searched for a while but could not find a reference to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
void add(thrust::device_vector<Data> *d_matrix) {
   &d_matrix[1].total = &d_matrix[1].first + &d_matrix[1].second;
}
```

In this code, `d_matrix` parameter is actually a **pointer** to an object of type `thrust::device_vector<Data>`. The expression `&d_matrix[1].total` is due to C++ operator precedence evaluated such that `d_matrix[1]` is considered to be the 2nd element of some non-existing array of elements of type `thrust::device_vector<Data>`, since a pointer can be treated as an array automatically. This (non-existing) 2nd element is then subject of `.total` member access, which does not exist.

Try `(*d_matrix)[1].total = ...` instead.

---

Also I am not sure that your code is correct. For example, you don't specify the size (number of elements, not size of an object) of neither your `host_vector` nor `device_vector`. You also `cudaMemcpy` vector object themselves; does it copy their content as well? Is it even allowed? I have no experience with Thrust, but according [this page](https://thrust.github.io/), there are much simpler way how to create `device_vector`.

Comment: I tried that but the error persists. I'm just not sure how to access the vector memory in device code using CUDA.

Comment: Even after all this is done (and it is all perfectly correct), the whole idea in the original code is completely wrong and can never be made to work.